# not work query only in single page (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, categories

My codes work on home page. But they do not work on single pages.

The reason is the following condition:

```
cat = '. $categories
```

All my code is:

```
         <div class="sidebar-widget">
        <h4 class="widget-title">most commented</h4>
        <?php
        function filter_where($where = ''){
            $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
            return $where;
        }
            add_filter('posts_where','filter_where');
            $category = get_the_category(); 
            $categorys =  $category[0]->cat_ID;
            if ( is_home() ) {
                query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=5&orderby=comment_count&order=DESC');
            }
            else {
                query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=5&orderby=comment_count&order=DESC&cat=' . $categorys);
            }
            while (have_posts()): the_post();
        ?>

        <figure class="card-horizontal thum">
          <figcaption>
            <a target="_blank" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="inner-card">
                <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' );?>
            <img class="card-thumb lazy-loaded" data-src="<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>" src="<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>" style="background-image: url(&quot;undefined&quot;);"> 

              <span class="card-title">
                <?php the_title();?>
              </span>
            </a>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>
      </div>
```

Is there a problem get_the_category();?